# Can possible Make outbound call Using Twilio Elastic SIP Trunk and FreePBX by programming or API?

Tags: twilio

We are find how to make outbound call Using Twilio Elastic SIP Trunk and FreePBX so any way to connect via Rest API

Because Twilio programable voice are very high costly

Hi

Can possible Make outbound call Using Twilio Elastic SIP Trunk and FreePBX by programming or API?

If yes please give source code for connect Twilio Elastic SIP Trunk

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the instructions from this [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/12/how-to-configure-twilio-elastic-sip-trunking-with-freepbx.html)?